# Automate click on a specific button on a website (that only pops up after 30 minutes)

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I am trying to automate the clicking of a specific button on a website that only appears after 30 minutes of being logged in to the website. I have already looked in to how to do this but my primary issue is that the button does not have an ID.

The other issue is that this button only appears on the page after roughly 30 minutes, I am experimenting with tampermonkey as a way of running this script in my browser, however I am unsure on how to script it.

[image: Screenshot of elements in page]

I found somebody else with a similar issue - this was their solution

```
For Each btn In document.getElementsByTagName("button") 
     If btn.innerText = "Refresh Token Now" Then 
           btn.Click()
           End If
```

however this does not seem to be working for me, I have also tried the following

```
For Each btn In document.getElementsByClassName("wb-button wb-button--secondary wb-button--small")
    If btn.innerText = "Refresh Token Now" Then
        btn.Click();
        End If
```

If somebody could please assist/point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout and do something after 30 minute being load, 1 sec = 1000

```js
const halfhour = 1000 * 60 * 30;

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Run after 30 minute');
  document.querySelector('.refresh').click();
}, halfhour);

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(b => {
  if (b.innerText.indexOf('Refresh') != -1) {
    b.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log('Refresh has been click');
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="close">Close</button>
  <button class="refresh">Refresh</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Taurus,

Thanks for your answer - however, you'll have to forgive my ignorance as I don't have much experience with JS, but I don't see how the code would link through to the specific button that I need to click - when i inspect the elements in chrome I noticed that both of the buttons in the dialogue box are listed as the same class - the only discernable difference between the two is the text - hence I was messing around with:

If btn.innerText = "Refresh Token Now" Then
        btn.Click();

Comment: then add class to your button or id

Comment: Ahhh, okay - sorry for the confusion, I should have stated clearly in my original post that this website is not mine - so I have no control over the source code of the webpage so cannot add anything to the button.
  
`code` document.querySelector('.wb-button wb-button--secondary wb-button--small').innerText = "Refresh Token Now".click(); `code` - maybe something along these lines? but I am clearly missing something as it does not work

Comment: Not your but want to add new js file? is'nt weird

Comment: I stated in my original post that I wanted to use a browser plugin (tampermonkey) to run the script..

Comment: I have some change to the snipped above that should work like you want